# Simplifying Blender's UI

Tags: interface

I want to clean Blender's UI to make it simpler to use for visualizating 3d models.

The idea is to remove all the UI's components and add 5 buttons with some basic functions, like open file, measure tool, etc. I found the source files written in C of the UI in /blender/source/blender/editors/interface and written in Python in /bin/Release/2.80/scripts/startup/bl_ui.

I started modifying /scripts/startup/bl_ui/init.py, but there are some areas that haven't been removed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is generally **not** a good idea. Once your "non-experienced users" want to become more experienced, they start looking up stuff online. When that happens, they find their way around Blender even less than if they would have started with the "complicated" UI. Blender never will be a "5 buttons to press - boom! - result" kind of software, no matter what you are going to try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to blender development.

Comment: I have explained myself wrong. I was referring to simplify the interface to view and edit 3D models.

Comment: Can you edit this question and condense it to: *"I tried hiding this area with python with the code XZ, but it is unchanged. How can I remove it?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before coding your own custom version of blender, start with what blender already offers -

- **Maximise Area** makes the current editor (usually the 3D view) take up the entire window area while leaving the Info Bar at the top and viewport headers visible. In 2.7x press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑ Up arrow</kbd>, in 2.80 press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>
- **Fullscreen Area** makes the current editor take up the entire window without the info bar or headers being visible. In 2.7x press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, in 2.80 press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>
- [**Screens**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/screens.html) are preset window layouts that we can easily switch between, in 2.80 these are replaced with [workspaces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/workspaces.html). If any of the included screens do not suit your requirements you can create your own or adjust the included screens. By setting up screens and saving them in your startup blend file, you can have them each time you use blender. This means you can manually setup a layout the way you want and always have it available and active when you first start blender. Note that you may want to disable the [Load UI option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/preferences/file.html) to prevent other peoples screens being loaded when you open a blend file.

By making the 3D view full screen you still have the tool shelf and properties [regions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html). You can use python to define your own custom [panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html) to make specific things/actions easily available to you and by putting it in an addon it can always be there. You may also want to get creative and misuse the ability to alter header contents with an addon, say you never use the VSE, then you can setup a screen that has a small VSE area available that shows buttons or menus that you define.